# Order related emails are not being sent in Magento 2.4 (Resolved)

Tags: orders, smtp, mail

We are using Magento 2 SMTP Plugin for mail communication.
Magento 2.4 is sending user registration, forget password, email confirmation, abandoned cart emails without any issues.
I have created and assigned email templates for order events, Disable email communication is set to No.
Asynchronous Sending is set to No and Enabled for Order in Sales email section.
I am not finding any errors related to Cron in my Magento logs.

Please help

Comment: Did u try executing this command - bin/magento cron:run or after an order is placed got to the admin order page and try sending mail again from that page by clicking on the "send mail" button to try if that works. If not, debug the the errors in var/log directory by checking all the log files. From the given above information this is what I can come through, I hope this resolves.

Comment: Hi Bharath. Thanks a lot for your insights and you brought me closer to the root cause of the problem. The order related emails are not even being sent when sent manually through Orders page, I think I have to check logs later today.

Answer (score 2):

If you're facing issues only in the sales email, please check whether the sales order email is enabled or not once in the following path.

**Stores -> Configurations -> Sales -> Sales Email -> Order**

Enabled = Yes (Check in all the scopes)

[image]

If it doesn't works,then check the logs under /var/log

Comment: Found the root cause and i am providing this information only for users who experience the issue like me.
Just check whether you can send emails from that particular email address from th smtp plugin, In my case, i used email aliases, for different email addresses, I forgotten to create alias for magento transnational email,s

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue as yours. I upgraded Magento from 2.3 to 2.4.4-p2 and using mageplaza/magento-2-smtp, I can receive registration, and contact form emails but no Order Confirmation Emails.

Can you share the info that you solved the issue?

Thanks.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/204654)